# Decryption failed: No secret key using GPG

Tags: linux, unix, encryption, public-key-encryption, gnupg

Last night I setup Pass Password Manager. I used **gpg2**, and followed this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@chasinglogic/the-definitive-guide-to-password-store-c337a8f023a1). I didn't implement git integration. Everything worked successfully. To view my password I had to enter my master key, exactly like how I want it. This morning I try to use pass. In my terminal I typed in

```
pass account/adobe/my@email.com
```

I get the following error:

```
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

It didn't ask me to enter my master key. I tried restarting gpg-agent, I tried editing `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`, but nothing is working.

This is how my `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` looks like:

```
default-cache-ttl 28800
# 8 hours
pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-curses
allow-loopback-pinentry
```

I should mention that I am using Linux Subsystem on Windows 10.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for [programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/about).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put this in ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf  :

```
default-cache-ttl 3153600000
pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-curses
allow-loopback-pinentry
```

After enter the following  commands:

```
$ gpgconf --kill gpg-agent
$ gpg-connect-agent /bye
```